# ecs, automated task/image deletion working strangely

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

```
Sep 30 03:52:21 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9e8ab5b) entered disabled state
Sep 30 03:52:21 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9e8ab5b) entered blocking state
Sep 30 03:52:21 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9e8ab5b) entered forwarding state
Sep 30 04:40:29 ip-172-31-29-22 dockerd: time="2020-09-30T04:40:29.291514159Z" level=info msg="Container a0c157da8a9d45d979a415382d3dfaaa4940591b32d5d04cf5808b0778a1612e failed to exit within 30 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
Sep 30 04:40:31 ip-172-31-29-22 dockerd: time="2020-09-30T04:40:31.345251918Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Sep 30 04:40:31 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9e8ab5b) entered disabled state
Sep 30 04:40:31 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9e8ab5b) entered disabled state
Sep 30 04:40:31 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9e8ab5b) entered disabled state
Sep 30 04:40:38 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth7d9766d) entered blocking state
Sep 30 04:40:38 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth7d9766d) entered disabled state
Sep 30 04:40:38 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth7d9766d) entered blocking state
Sep 30 04:40:38 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth7d9766d) entered forwarding state
Sep 30 07:22:48 ip-172-31-29-22 dockerd: time="2020-09-30T07:22:48.317828353Z" level=info msg="Container 5df345cbca604065745c14841b33a2244ddc27c8cadd73bc818d1b3d26cef462 failed to exit within 30 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
Sep 30 07:22:50 ip-172-31-29-22 dockerd: time="2020-09-30T07:22:50.429858584Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Sep 30 07:22:50 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth7d9766d) entered disabled state
Sep 30 07:22:50 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth7d9766d) entered disabled state
Sep 30 07:22:50 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth7d9766d) entered disabled state
Sep 30 07:22:58 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth32523d0) entered blocking state
Sep 30 07:22:58 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth32523d0) entered disabled state
Sep 30 07:22:59 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth32523d0) entered blocking state
Sep 30 07:22:59 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth32523d0) entered forwarding state
Sep 30 13:48:15 ip-172-31-29-22 dockerd: time="2020-09-30T13:48:15.196338184Z" level=info msg="Container 670ce20686c2854d14c5a114c7077cdb28734fe88e3a0065303d4096da4108cb failed to exit within 30 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
Sep 30 13:48:19 ip-172-31-29-22 dockerd: time="2020-09-30T13:48:19.388866897Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Sep 30 13:48:19 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth32523d0) entered disabled state
Sep 30 13:48:19 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth32523d0) entered disabled state
Sep 30 13:48:19 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth32523d0) entered disabled state
Sep 30 13:48:26 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth0ffa70b) entered blocking state
Sep 30 13:48:26 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth0ffa70b) entered disabled state
Sep 30 13:48:26 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth0ffa70b) entered blocking state
Sep 30 13:48:26 ip-172-31-29-22 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth0ffa70b) entered forwarding state
```

These are logs of `/var/log/messages` in aws ecs ec2 instance.

The following lines indicate my containers are routinely given a `kill` request.
and `docker0` is alternating between `enabled` state and `disabled` state.

I do see spikes in our webserver response time and I am speculating if this is the cause for it.

> Sep 30 13:48:15 ip-172-31-29-22 dockerd:
> time="2020-09-30T13:48:15.196338184Z" level=info msg="Container
> 670ce20686c2854d14c5a114c7077cdb28734fe88e3a0065303d4096da4108cb
> failed to exit within 30 seconds of signal 15 - using the force" Sep
> 30 13:48:19 ip-172-31-29-22 dockerd:
> time="2020-09-30T13:48:19.388866897Z" level=info msg="ignoring event"
> module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete
> type="*events.TaskDelete"

Weird thing is, I have 2 ec2 running (with same ami and same all, same task), and one is showing the above logs, another one has no sign of `*events.TaskDelete` getting received.

should I disable the message `taskdelete` alltogether?

The taskdelete seems to be from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/automated_image_cleanup.html

Comment: Any luck? We have a very similar issue, and trying to solve it in the past month with no luck. Any help would be welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: @sztech sorry i can't remember, i had problems with instance with low memory.. getting killed, but not sure if this was it..